# How to see the plain CSS of all tailwind classes

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css, inline-styles

I need plain CSS of all tailwind classes. I want to convert both (custom and tailwind classes) into inline CSS. I've found some tools online that convert external CSS to inline CSS if provided with an external stylesheet (they fetch class details from the stylesheet and add their classes as inline CSS). I'm able to convert my custom classes into inline CSS this way but am not able to do so for tailwind CSS as there is no plain CSS for tailwind classes available.

Comment: Actually, there is currently no dedicated tool available specifically designed to convert Tailwind CSS classes to inline CSS. However, there is a workaround that can be employed. You can utilize Chat GPT to assist you in this task by providing your code and requesting the conversion of your Tailwind classes into inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the build command for the app, tailwind generates a minified .css file in the build directory. There you can find all the individual classes generated by the tailwind config.

PS: Make sure you are not using the `jit` compiler otherwise it will only generate the classes which you have used in your src files.

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I've run the build command and it has generated the build folder in my directory that contains css folder but I couldn't find any proper css file. Instead, I found files with "chunk.css" prefix containing css properties but not plain CSS.